# What does FormulaVersion do in Range.Replace

Tags: excel, vba

What does the  `FormulaVersion`-parameter in `Range.Replace` do? I tried looking it up in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace), but the page for `Replace` doesn't include this parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my limited testing, if you use `xlReplaceFormulas` then any dynamic array formulas that have a replacement made are converted to use the `@` operator and no longer spill. Using `xlReplaceFormulas2` leaves them as spilling formulas. If you are trying to remove the `@` operator, you *have* to use `xlReplaceFormulas2` or it just gets put back.

Comment: Seems likely this is it. Thanks.